# Page Curl in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

I am developing an application like a comic book. There I am fetching data(like image and text)in an array. I want to add page curl animation to show the different character's images and some text. I have gone through "Leaves" example but it was only for PDFs and Images(As far as I got). How can I implement that page curl animation in my app ?

Regards

Comment: Have you happened to look at the beta SDK to see if anything in there might do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by this way also.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting code I use to curl a view in animation.

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:101 forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self.setView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

alternatively you can use 102 in transition to make opposite curling of a view

Comment: Probably better to use the constants `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` and `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown` rather than those values.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but this one I'd checked before. My problem is - I don't have any image-only or pdf-only to curl. I am fetching some texts and some character-images from web(suppose I have one Image view and one textview)and I want to curl it up. On the next page again some different image and text view. –

Answer (score 1):

IF u want to apply page curl effect then i tell u so many links but this is best link. If it  will not work then tell me i will tell another one.
[Page curl](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/06/app-store-safe-page-curl-animations/)

Comment: Thanks for quick response but this one I'd checked before. My problem is - I don't have any image-only or pdf-only to curl. I am fetching some texts and some character-images from web(suppose I have one Image view and one textview)and I want to curl it up. On the next page again some different image and text view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mini app, it works and you can adapt it to your purposes.

https://github.com/Zobotron/Sfoglina-raw